# className is not appended to the js object

Tags: javascript, html, classname

```
var obj = document.createElement('div');
obj.className = 'className';
```

This will output the div element with class appended to it.

```
var obj = {
divE : function(){
   return document.createElement('div')}      
}
obj.divE().className = 'className';
```

This doesnot append the class name to the div element i.e. obj.divE()

What could be the reason? How to append class to obj.divE();

Comment: How do you want to use `obj` afterwards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The returned value of `obj.divE().className = 'className';` statement is `className` string. Your code creates an element, modifies it's `className` property and effectively doesn't do anything. If you store the returned value:

```
var value = obj.divE().className = 'className';
```

then the stored value is `'className'` string not the created element. You have to create the element, store it and then update the `className` just like your first snippet.

If you want to create a helper function you can code:

```
var obj = {
  divE : function(cls) {
     var div = document.createElement('div');
     if ( cls ) {
        div.className = cls;
     }
     return div;
  }      
}

var createdElement = obj.divE('className');
var anotherElement = obj.divE();
```

Comment: So using this value variable how to append the className again to the element ?

Answer (score 2):

use

```
var ob = obj.divE();
    ob.className = "className";
```

every time you calling obj.divE() directly it is creating a new element object.so
 `obj.divE().className = 'ClassName';`
  `obj.divE().id= 'ClassName';`
both lines creating different object.
You have to assign it some where to reuse.